# How to drop all rows in pandas dataframe with negative values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a mix of column dtypes, float64 and object.

I need to dynamically drop all rows that have any negative values.  Here is what I have so far:

```
 df = df[(df > 0).all(axis=1)]
```

But because some of the columns are not numeric, it basically wipes the entire df.

How can I build this to only consider numerical columns? There are too many columns to do manually do something like this for each column, but this does work if I had to go 1 by 1:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['col1'] < 0].index, inplace=True)
```

whenever I try putting this into a looping statement I run into errors about comparing strings to ints.

I just want to scan every column per row, and if I detect a number, and it's negative, drop the entire row.  I feel like I'm making this too hard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to get only numeric columns, and keep your code.

```
df[df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).ge(0).all(1)]
```

---

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4],
                   'col2': [-1, -2, 3, 4],
                   'col3': ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'col4': [1,2,3,4]})


   col1  col2 col3  col4
0     1    -1    a     1
1     2    -2    b     2
2     3     3    c     3
3     4     4    d     4
```

gives

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
2   3       3       c       3
3   4       4       d       4
```