# How to delete any row for which a corresponding column has a negative value using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have been given a CSV data file. Using JupyterHub, Python and Pandas I have been able to read the dataframe and have deleted any rows with NaN values.
I am looking to do the same for any values that are negative.
I have tried to search a similar problem on thsi site, but can't seem to find a solution to try that fits well.
Below is how I deleted the rows with NaNs
Please help!

```
df=pd.read_csv("cereal.csv")
df1=df.dropna(how='any',axis =0).reset_index(drop=True)
df1.shape
df1.head()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop all rows in pandas dataframe with negative values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533004/how-to-drop-all-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-with-negative-values)

Comment: I have tried the code given there, however nothing changed on my table. There definitely is some negative values in there.

Comment: Please create a [reprex] then, including sample data.

Comment: the example given by @BigBen looks ideal. Which part when implemented did not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop rows for which in a specific column the value is negative using `pandas.DataFrame.drop` as follows:

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA': [-1, 2, 3, 4, None],
    'colB': [True, True, False, False, True],
})

df = df.drop(df.index[df['colA'] < 0])
```

Output:

```python
>>> df
   colA   colB
1   2.0   True
2   3.0  False
3   4.0  False
4   NaN   True
```

Comment: This has worked! Thank you so much :) However I did have to do each column separately. Is there a way to do this via a loop, where it goes through each column not just one?

Comment: `for i in df.columns: df = df.drop(df.index[df[i] < 0])`. Also, if it worked for you then I would suggest you to see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option, similar syntax but doesn't use `.drop`. Retain the rows where condition is not met (`~` works as a negation):

```
>>> df.loc[~(df['colA'] < 0)]  
   colA   colB
1   2.0   True
2   3.0  False
3   4.0  False
4   NaN   True
```

And another one, for you to choose depending if you want the NaN values in your "colA" or not:

```
>>> df.loc[df['colA'] >= 0)]
   colA   colB
1   2.0   True
2   3.0  False
3   4.0  False
```